# Как применить SVG-фильтр (фильтры) для создания цветной SVG-формы всего силуэта?

Tags: css3, html5, svg, filter

У меня есть изображение в PNG, например шахматной фигуры (белого короля).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существует ли простой способ применения фильтров SVG к этму изображению для получения SVG, имеющего такую же форму (контур) и заполненного одним цветом, например, красным?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57650474/7394871

Answer (score 1):

- В случае, если ваше изображение имеет белую заливку и прозрачную
  внешнюю поверхность, тогда да, вы можете сделать это с помощью
  фильтра SVG.

```css
img {
  filter: url(#colorise);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorise">
      <!-- Заполнение области фильтра красным -->
      <feFlood flood-color="red" result="colour"/>
      <!-- Обрежьте красный цвет до того, что находится "внутри"  изображения, то есть непрозрачно -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="colour" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      <!-- Умножьте обрезанную красную форму с исходным изображением. Черные части остаются черными. Белые части становятся красными. -->
      <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
```

- Как сделать все изображение красным, включая черные части.

```css
img {
  filter: url(#colorise);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorise">
      <!-- Заполните область фильтра красным -->
      <feFlood flood-color="red" result="colour"/>
      <!-- Обрежьте красный цвет до того, что находится "внутри"  изображения, то есть непрозрачно -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="colour" in2="SourceAlpha"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656454/7394871) @Paul LeBeau

Answer (score 1):

Когда добавлено изображение с помощью `<img>` остается только один способ изменения цвета - с помощью фильтров SVG или CSS.

Ниже пример изменения цвета при наведении курсора с помощью фильтра SVG:

```css
img {
 
}
 img:hover {
 filter: url(#colorise);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorise">
      <!-- Заполнение области фильтра красным -->
      <feFlood flood-color="red" result="colour"/>
      <!-- Обрежьте красный цвет до того, что находится "внутри"  изображения, то есть непрозрачно -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="colour" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      <!-- Умножьте обрезанную красную форму с исходным изображением. Черные части остаются черными. Белые части становятся красными. -->
      <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wQ.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wB.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wN.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png"/>
```

**Пример с анимацией увеличения фигур при наведении**

```css
img {
margin:0.8em;
 transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
 img:hover {
 filter: url(#colorise);
 transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <filter id="colorise">
      <!-- Заполнение области фильтра жёлтым -->
      <feFlood flood-color="gold" result="colour"/>
      <!-- Обрежьте красный цвет до того, что находится "внутри"  изображения, то есть непрозрачно -->
      <feComposite operator="in" in="colour" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      <!-- Умножьте обрезанную красную форму с исходным изображением. Черные части остаются черными. Белые части становятся красными. -->
      <feBlend mode="multiply" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wK.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wQ.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wB.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wN.png"/>
<img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/oakmac/chessboardjs@1.0.0/website/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wP.png"/>
```